# Creating ICEfaces application example connecting beans and Facelets

Tags: jsf-2, javabeans, facelets, icefaces

I'm new in developing web applications and I installed the ICEfaces plugin. I found [this tutorial](http://www.icesoft.org/wiki/display/ICE/Creating+ICEfaces+Applications+with+Eclipse)  to learn how to work with it and the first given example dont work in my IDE.

Its about the last part of the tutorial where it shows how to use a dateTimeEntry in a webapp. 
So I followed the instructions so that my index.xhtml looks like this:

```
<?xml version='1.0' encoding='UTF-8' ?>
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"
xmlns:ui="http://java.sun.com/jsf/facelets"
xmlns:f="http://java.sun.com/jsf/core"
xmlns:h="http://java.sun.com/jsf/html"
xmlns:icecore="http://www.icefaces.org/icefaces/core"
xmlns:ace="http://www.icefaces.org/icefaces/components"
xmlns:ice="http://www.icesoft.com/icefaces/component">

<h:body>
<form>
    <ace:dateTimeEntry id="dateTimeEntryId"
        value="#{yourBean.selectDateProperty}" timeZone="Canada/Mountain"
        pattern="MMM/dd/yyyy" style="width: 729px; " renderAsPopup="true"> 
    </ace:dateTimeEntry><br />
</form>
</h:body>
</html>
```

And my java bean like this:

```
package org.icefaces.view;

import java.io.Serializable;
import java.util.Date;

import javax.faces.bean.ManagedBean;
import javax.faces.bean.ViewScoped;

import org.icefaces.ace.event.DateSelectEvent;

@ManagedBean(name= "yourBean")
@ViewScoped
public class YourBean implements Serializable {

/**
 * 
 */
private static final long serialVersionUID = 5058131064162864510L;

private Date selectDateProperty = new Date(System.currentTimeMillis());

public Date getSelectDateProperty() {
    return selectDateProperty;
}

public void setSelectDateProperty(Date selectDateProperty) {
    this.selectDateProperty = selectDateProperty;
}

public void dateSelectListener(DateSelectEvent event) {
    setSelectDateProperty(event.getDate());
  }
}
```

The structure of the project looks like this:

[image: Project]

The point is, that in the tutorial there is no location given where to save the java beans. So I thougt it has to saved in the java resources directory, but I'm not sure because the app dont work. I just get a blank screen. The server and the configuration of it is valid I think because I can drop some Img or buttons and see the result in the browser. So I think I did not really understand how the java beans are connected with the xhtml files. I thougt it works with ManagedBean - attribute but I'm not sure about that.

Comment: I found out, that I have to call the .jsf file in the browser to make the textfield visible. But it still has no such functionality of a calender.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Complete list of sample codes you can find here
http://anonsvn.icesoft.org/repo/icefaces3/trunk/icefaces/samples

Answer (score 0):

Well I found out, that the connection of the javabeans and the variables in the xhtml file has to created in faces-config.xml in this form:

```
<managed-bean>
  <managed-bean-name> [bean-name-of-java-class] </managed-bean-name>
  <managed-bean-class> [fullpath-to-java-file] </managed-bean-class>
  <managed-bean-scope>[scope]</managed-bean-scope>
</managed-bean>
```